# Tree command package installation?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, usb, bootable, tree

I tried to use the `tree` command in a bootable USB Ubuntu environment but it showed that it is not installed so I tried `sudo apt install tree`, but it didn't work and reported that it was unable to locate package and also said to enable component universe. I don't know what component universe is. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable universe, run

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then update the indexes:

```
sudo apt update
```

You’ll be able to install the `tree` package once that’s done:

```
sudo apt install tree
```